# How to fix The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes without loosing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Today I try to convert my wordpress blog MySQL database table (only wordpress system table) engines from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`. I can convert all the wordpress system tables, except `_posts` table. When I run this command,

> ALTER TABLE table_prefix_here_posts ENGINE=InnoDB;

I get following error.

> #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

I search on Google and found that I can fix it by doping the table. But in my situation, as far as I know, if I drop the _posts table, I lose all my blog posts. Therefore are there anyway to convert my _posts table to InnoDB without loosing my posts (data)?

Comment: upgrade to 5.6 then you can use InnoDB Full-Text Search

Comment: Few months ago i ask why MySQL not update to v5.6. Then my VPS hosting company mentioned it's not fully support WHM.

Answer (score 3):

FULLTEXT indexes are supported in InnoDB tables only starting from MYSQL 5.6 so try to update MYSQL and after that alter table's engine